# Possible to use Flow when developing VS Code extensions?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, flowtype, vscode-extensions

I know I can use Typescript, but any way to use Flow for a VS Code extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can write an [VS Code extension with either TypeScript or **JavaScript**](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/overview#_writing-an-extension), it's totally possible to write an extension with Flow types. You'll need to strip the types at the end of your build process with something like [babel](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-flow-strip-types) or [flow-remove-types](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-remove-types), but it's totally doable. At the end, your Flow typed code will be converted to regular old JavaScript and that's what will be loaded by VS Code.